# What are typical SMTP relay limits to be aware of when sending out newsletters?

Tags: email, bulk

Is there a *typical* SMTP relay limit to keep in mind when sending out email newsletters to large numbers of subscribers, or does it vary wildly depending on the email provider?

Also, is the limit generally hourly, or daily.... or are there sometimes SMTP limits for both timeframes?

We are considering using MailChimp to sidestep this issue, but I would rather know exactly what the limits we are dealing with are likely to be first before paying a monthly subscription fee for a new service.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the provider and the service plan you have. But normally it's between 250 and 500 emails per day. Some providers give you the option to buy more relays. You should check this first with your email provider.

Comment: Thanks. If anyone else can wade in with their opinion as well, that would be good- particularly if anyone has experience of default SMTP relay limits outside this range of 250-500.

I've asked my carrier for information regarding our limits and will update when I find out.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to answer this properly, but to answer your actual question, it varies too much.

Other answers say some figures such as 250-500 a day and it is *dangerous* to follow this (although it's certainly not inaccurate in any way). Some allow up to 1000 a day or more, some much less, and some are limited to the hour! Others are limited to number or recipients per email. Some by the domain, others could be by individual mail within domain... the list goes on.

The things you need to do is

1. Speak to your ISP and ask them about the limitations
2. Don't abuse it! Get good quality mass mail software which limits the amounts of emails it sends per minute!
3. Talk to a company who send emails on your behalf

For example, I wrote my own called AMEmailer (which is not live for download so don't look for it) but it allowed the user to specify during what parts of the day to send emails and how many to send every 10 minutes.

I ran this via my own mail server which had no limitations, but I still limited it to 10 emails every 10 minutes (therefore 1 email per minute) and never had an issue with being blocked or overloading the server with so much traffic it hangs.

Remember, if you abuse the system, your IP may be black listed, then your company can no longer email to anyone on that server/domain etc. This could be disastrous to business. Again, to re-iterate it, let your news letter take an extra day/week or month to send and don't risk it.

If you need more resources, get another server, or pay a third party because if you do, then they take that risk (typically).

Comment: You're quite right. It varies a LOT. Our provider (Zenutech) limits it to 150/hour.